# Flutter: How to prevent BottomNavigationBar from rebuilding on tab change or push to other screen?

Tags: flutter

I have a BottomNavigationBar with 2 tabs (Screen A & B). Please check the below steps for the issue:

1. My Current Tab is Screen A and I Navigate to Screen X.
2. Firstly Screen A’s build method is executed and then secondly Screen X’s build method is invoked.
3. When I pop back to previous screen (Screen A) then Screen X’s build method is executed and then Screen A’s build method is invoked once again.

Comment: Please provide more detail and codes.

Comment: here you can see code: https://github.com/jaylad-fin/FlutterTabBarDemo

Comment: also getting same issue.